# accent character not getting picked up

Tags: r

I have a dataset where some rows contain an accent character and this isn't getting picked up by my code correctly. I did some googling and someone suggested using a ` but this didn't work.

nb. I'm using Jupyter notebook

Here is the code I'm trying to run and the special character can be seen in it;

```
NewGroupfactsDS <- groupfactsDS
NewGroupfactsDS <- NewGroupfactsDS %>%
filter(GroupName %in% c("All households",
                        "Income quintile 1 (low)",
                        "Income quintile 2",
                        "Income quintile 3",
                        "Income quintile 4",
                        "Income quintile 5 (high)",
                        "Māori",
                        "Superannuitant"
                       ))
```

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: Are you using R Studio? If so you can try "Save with encoding..." and choose UTF-8 or other encodings. That has fixed similar issues for me in the past.

Comment: I'm using jupyter notebook

Comment: Please post enough of `groupfactsDS` that we can run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by viewing the table in jupyter notebook then copy and pasting how the terminal was printing the word which was as;
`MÄori`